# QGIS, Print layout, same UUID on two pages

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am trying to display the same UUID on two pages.
I would like to assign the two pages clearly.

My procedure so far:

- Page 1, a label field with the following expression: `'ID: '[% uuid() %]'`
- On page 2, I have the problem to show the same UUID.

I have tried with the following expression: `item_variables('MY_ITEM_ID')`.
but I can't get the content of my first item.
Does anyone have an idea how I could continue?

Comment: A UUID is usually generated as unique identifier for something. What are you using it for here? Could it be stored somewhere else in the project or data?

Comment: In this case, it is not possible to save an ID for the printout in the project. I think... 
I want to use the layout via Qgis and QWC2. 

I need a unique ID for each print. The ID must be visible on both pages...

Comment: Would a timestamp based hash work?

Comment: that was my first idear.
I used year, month, day, hour, minute and second. But already at the first attempt I had different values for the seconds. 
It is too long to go only to the minute, because the same ID shows on two prints.